# Azure Tools cannot read Service Definition File

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, hangfire

I have a hangfire worker role with the following service definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="Company.ServiceA.Cloud.Hangfire" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WorkerRole name="Company.ServiceA.HangfireWorkerRole" vmsize="Standard_A8_v2">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.HangfireDb.Server" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.HangfireDb.Password" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.HangfireDb.User" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.HangfireDb.Database" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.ReadonlyDB.Server" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.ReadonlyDB.Password" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.ReadonlyDB.User" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.Redis.Progress" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.Redis.Progress.DatabaseId" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.ReadonlyDB.Database" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.DefaultDB.Server" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.DefaultDB.Password" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.DefaultDB.User" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.DefaultDB.Database" />
      <Setting name="ServiceA.CalculationCache.Disabled" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Some values changed for security reasons.

When I try to debug my cloud project, I see the following error:

```
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
Error reading Service Definition file
C:/Temp/ServiceDefinition.csdef
```

I'm using Azure Tools 2.7.1. Hangfire 1.6.19.

Is my file misformatted? I've read the documentation on Service Definition files here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-model-and-package#csdef
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557552.aspx

and everything seems to match up.

It's quite ridiculous how little error information is given. Surely microsoft can come up with something more specific than this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem because the compute emulator does not recognize the value of the vmsize attribute, even though it is a valid Azure instance size.

In my case, it was failing for "Standard_D2_v3".  I was able to debug locally when changing to "Standard_D2_v2".

Comment: Forgot that I asked this question. I also was able to get it to run locally by changing the vm size to small. Had to change it back to Standard_A8_v2 when I was done though. Super frustrating.